# Change margins in a Word.Application document from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, margins

I have Excel VBA to copy and paste from Excel to Word.  The code to change the line spacing works fine but the code to change the margins does not.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyXLStoDOC()

' ****************************************************************************
' *      Make sure to set a reference to Microsoft Word Object Library!!!    *
' ****************************************************************************

'  Source of code:  http://mrspreadsheets.com/1/post/2012/09/vba-code-snippet.html

    'declare local variables and constants
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim rRange1 As Range, rRange2 As Range
    Const sDocPath As String = "D:\Corinne\5   RALF WORK\A_RALFS Jobs\Document2.docx"

    'set ranges to copy
    Set rRange1 = Worksheets("4_Data Form").Range("B2:K68")
    Set rRange2 = Worksheets("4_Transport").Range("C13:J53")

    'open the Word document, if it doesn't exist, then create one
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oDoc = GetObject(sDocPath)
    Set oWord = oDoc.Parent
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add
    End If
    oWord.Visible = True

    'Change Word sheet settings

    'set Page Setup properties - Page Orientation, Page Size & Margins:


     With oWord.ActiveDocument.PageSetup
        .TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.8)
        .BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.8)
        .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.8)
        .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.8)
     End With


    'copy and paste first range into Word
     rRange1.Copy
     oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste


    'copy and paste second range into Word after pagebreak
    rRange2.Copy
    'remove the next line if you want to paste rRange2 directly after rRange1
    oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
    oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste



    With oDoc.Content.ParagraphFormat
        .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle
        .SpaceAfter = 0
        .SpaceAfter = False
    End With


    'Clean up objects
    Set oDoc = Nothing
    Set rRange1 = Nothing
    Set rRange2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you copy and paste a range from Excel into a Word document, it gets inserted as a Table.  The resulting table will adjust *it's own margins* to fit the data in the columns being pasted.  You'll likely have to grab a reference to the resulting Table and format that:

```
'...

'copy and paste first range into Word
rRange1.Copy
oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste

With oDoc.Tables(1)
   'apply table formatting here.
End With

'copy and paste second range into Word after pagebreak
rRange2.Copy
'remove the next line if you want to paste rRange2 directly after rRange1
oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste

With oDoc.Tables(2)
    'apply table formatting here.
End With

'...
```

Comment: Thank you,this will help me to now know what is in control of the formatting during the copy/paste action